# How to get all opened url in browser using angularjs/javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get all opened tabs url in my application i tried below code

```
function list_session(callback) {

    chrome.windows.getAll({populate : true}, function (window_list) {
        var list = [];
        for(var i=0;i<window_list.length;i++) {
            list = list.concat(window_list[i].tabs);
        }
        console.log(list);
        if(callback) {
            callback(list);
        }
    });
}
list_session(function(tab_list) {
    //use array of tabs
    console.log(tab_list);
});
```

i am getting below error

```
Cannot read property 'getAll' of undefined
```

please help me out to move forward..

Comment: if its duplicate can you please provide me the answer @georgeawg

Answer (score 1):

[`chrome.windows`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows) is only available when writing a Chrome extension.

It is not available when writing a webpage.

Browsers do not provide JavaScript running in a webpage with access to any information about other windows. That would be a serious security / privacy risk.

Comment: how can i get url can you help me out in this

Comment: I refer you back to the final paragraph of this answer.

Comment: i want to get only my application urls .is it possible to get(i dont want other info's)